# background-color:#070707; different in photoshop than in browser

Tags: html, photoshop, background-color

I'm coding a website with:

```
background-color:#070707;
```

That color should be a very dark gray, just the way I see it in photoshop.
Now when I launch this in my browser (the background-color is set on the body using CSS, so it's not an exported image), the color is darker than in Photoshop.

I know there can be differences when exporting images due to color profiling, but when setting the color code, how can this be different from photoshop?

Answer (score 4):

Photoshop might be rendering the colors using its built-in color matching/proofing engine while the browser probably does not use one.

Try getting Photoshop's color settings right (CTRL+SHIFT+K) and change proof setup (View > Proof Setup) to match that of a typical monitor.

Answer (score 3):

I think it depends which color model are you using in photoshop:

- RGB
- CMYK
- LAB

Here is a good tutorial about the exact usage and differences of each of them:

http://www.deke.com/content/photoshop-top-40-feature-6-rgb-cmyk-and-lab

Answer (score 0):

Could you be defining it in photoshop as something other than a hex number? IIRC, there's Hue/Sat/something that can also give a 6-digit output. You're not viewing it on different monitors or something?

Answer (score 0):

`#070707` is not dark gray. It is almost black. Are you sure that the color palette in photoshop does not include alpha. Else try ['Choose Copy Color As HTML'](http://livedocs.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/10.0/help.html?content=WS466742C9-A632-4836-9773-E55A612D9297.html) option in color palette.

Answer (score 0):

Saving a file for the web is best done with "save for web" or ctrl/shift/alt (on the pc). This gives you many options for color output - ones that shouldn't change. However, if you choose a color out of the web gambut, it may be "correcting" it for the web. I agree with Glasnt's response - Check it under different monitors.

Gifs always make guesses to color combinations. Jpgs are given a range of accuracy. Pings are the most correct to color exports out of the series. Make sure you are saving RGB instead of any other format (LAB, CMYK, etc.).

Are you using mac or pc?

bam